# no instance of constructor "RobotDriveSwerve::RobotDriveSwerve" matches the argument list -- argument types are

Tags: c++

I'm going through and trying to create my `swerveDrive`, but I have an issue where the constructor doesn't match the argument list.

I've already tried going into the class and changing the arguments that would have been requested.

GenericEnclosure.h

```
class GenericEnclosure : public SwerveEnclosure {
public:

    GenericEnclosure(   std::string name,
                frc::SpeedController& m_moveMotor,
                frc::SpeedController& m_turnMotor,
                rev::CANEncoder& m_encoder,
                double m_gearRatio);
    ~GenericEnclosure();

};
```

RobotDriveSwerve.h file

```
class RobotDriveSwerve
{
public:
    RobotDriveSwerve(SwerveEnclosure* frontLeftWheel,
                     SwerveEnclosure* frontRightWheel,
                     SwerveEnclosure* rearLeftWheel,
                     SwerveEnclosure* rearRightWheel,
                     double width, double length);
    virtual ~RobotDriveSwerve() = default;
```

.cpp file

```
  //All Drive Motors
  rev::CANSparkMax m_leftFrontDriveMotor{1, rev::CANSparkMax::MotorType::kBrushless};
  rev::CANSparkMax m_leftBackDriveMotor{2, rev::CANSparkMax::MotorType::kBrushless};
  rev::CANSparkMax m_rightFrontDriveMotor{3, rev::CANSparkMax::MotorType::kBrushless};
  rev::CANSparkMax m_rightBackDriveMotor{4, rev::CANSparkMax::MotorType::kBrushless};

  //All Turn Motors
  rev::CANSparkMax m_leftFrontTurnMotor{5, rev::CANSparkMax::MotorType::kBrushless};
  rev::CANSparkMax m_leftBackTurnMotor{6, rev::CANSparkMax::MotorType::kBrushless};
  rev::CANSparkMax m_rightFrontTurnMotor{7, rev::CANSparkMax::MotorType::kBrushless};
  rev::CANSparkMax m_rightBackTurnMotor{8, rev::CANSparkMax::MotorType::kBrushless};

  //All Drive Encoders
  rev::CANEncoder m_leftFrontDriveEncoder = m_leftFrontDriveMotor.GetEncoder();
  rev::CANEncoder m_leftBackDriveEncoder = m_leftBackDriveMotor.GetEncoder();
  rev::CANEncoder m_rightFrontDriveEncoder = m_rightFrontDriveMotor.GetEncoder();
  rev::CANEncoder m_rightBackDriveEncoder = m_rightBackDriveMotor.GetEncoder();

  //All Turn Encoders
  rev::CANEncoder m_leftFrontTurnEncoder = m_leftFrontTurnMotor.GetEncoder();
  rev::CANEncoder m_leftBackTurnEncoder = m_leftBackTurnMotor.GetEncoder();
  rev::CANEncoder m_rightFrontTurnEncoder = m_rightFrontTurnMotor.GetEncoder();
  rev::CANEncoder m_rightBackTurnEncoder = m_rightBackTurnMotor.GetEncoder();

 const double GEAR_RATIO = (1988/1.2);
const double L = 24.5;
const double W = 20.5;

//Enclosure initialization
        GenericEnclosure swerveEnclosure1{"enc 1", m_rightFrontDriveMotor, m_rightFrontDriveMotor, m_rightFrontTurnEncoder,GEAR_RATIO};
        GenericEnclosure swerveEnclosure2{"enc 2", m_leftFrontDriveMotor, m_leftFrontTurnMotor, m_leftFrontTurnEncoder, GEAR_RATIO};
        GenericEnclosure swerveEnclosure3{"enc 3", m_leftBackDriveMotor, m_leftBackTurnMotor, m_leftBackTurnEncoder, GEAR_RATIO};
        GenericEnclosure swerveEnclosure4{"enc 4", m_rightBackDriveMotor, m_rightBackTurnMotor, m_rightBackTurnEncoder, GEAR_RATIO};

//Swerve Drive initialization
        RobotDriveSwerve swerveDrive{swerveEnclosure1, swerveEnclosure2, swerveEnclosure3, swerveEnclosure4, W, L};
```

The error comes from this line `RobotDriveSwerve swerveDrive{swerveEnclosure1, swerveEnclosure2, swerveEnclosure3, swerveEnclosure4, W, L};` and it throws this error `no instance of constructor "RobotDriveSwerve::RobotDriveSwerve" matches the argument list -- argument types are: (GenericEnclosure, GenericEnclosure, GenericEnclosure, GenericEnclosure, const double, const double)`. Everything compiles fine but this is the only line struggling. Sorry for all the code but it is a sizeable class to build properly. Huge thanks to all who are able to help!

Comment: The constructor decl says those first four arguments are pointers. You're passing concrete objects, and there is no conversion operator. In short, the error msg is telling you *exactly* what the problem is.  Unrelated, you may well have another entirely different problem (static initialization) if those definitions are actually globals.

Comment: The constructor for `RobotDriveSwerve` takes pointers you passed instances of objects.

Comment: What is unclear about the error? Your constructor accepts arguments of type `SwerveEnclosure*` (a pointer), while you are passing `GenericEnclosure` (not a pointer) to it.

Answer (score 1):

The `RobotDriveSwerve` constructor is looking for pointers. You need to use the 'address of' operator. Change

```
RobotDriveSwerve swerveDrive{swerveEnclosure1, swerveEnclosure2, swerveEnclosure3, swerveEnclosure4, W, L};
```

To

```
RobotDriveSwerve swerveDrive{&swerveEnclosure1, &swerveEnclosure2, &swerveEnclosure3, &swerveEnclosure4, W, L};
```

Comment: That depends on what does the class do with those pointers... I'd prefer to modify the constructor to accept const references; but if the class `RobotDriveSwerve` stores those pointers, the solution would be to pass smart pointers. Anyway we don't see the implementation of the `RobotDriveSwerve`.

Comment: just made the changes, the code compiled this time. thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

In the constructor of `RobotDriveSwerve` you expect the pointers to classes `GenericEnclosure` while you provide the references at the line where compiler produces the error.